# Does Excel table listobject has some kind of cache memory? repopulates deleted formulas

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code works with ListObjects in Excel 2010. 
Formulas in the table are SUMIFS that sum up the data based on values of the first few columns (parameters).

When i get a new data, macro does the following routine:

- 1-deletes the table's entire DataBodyRange
- 2-pastes new data into   the parameters columns (these are text values)
- 3-analyses the   granularity of new data and compiles new formulas
- 4-populates the   formulas.

**ISSUE:** 
the formulas should not appear before step 3, but they do as if I never deleted them. 
It's like the listobject has some kind of cache memory.

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

I will make an example file if noone knows a quick tip off top of your heads. 
Also, I have researched this a lot on here and google in general, haven't found anything so far.

Thank you for any responses in advance!

Kind regards
Lana

Comment: did any of these answers work for you? If so please mark it as 'answered'. Thanks

Comment: Hello both of you, sorry for the delay - Excel didn't like the vbnullstring, so i ended up doing deleting databodyrange in a number of ways as well as forcing the formula to be null string via "" which I suppose is the same thing. Thank you for your answers, much appreciated! Lana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It depends on how you are deleting the rows.

If you delete is with

```
ListObject.ListRows(n).Delete
```

only the data is deleted, the formula references, which are actually structured references unlike regular Excel formulae, are maintained.

You need to delete it completely, you can do something like

```
ListObject.DatabodyRange.ClearContents
ListOBject.DatabodyRange.Rows().Delete
```

This should take care of your problem

Comment: Hi, Thank you,  I delete it as ListObject.DatabodyRange.Delete - I will try your method and will let you know if it worked asap!

Answer (score 1):

It definitely remembers if there was a formula in a ListColumn. I'm not sure if it's a cache or just an undisclosed property of the ListColumn. If you explicitly set the listcolumn to vbNullString, you can effectively clear the cache.

This is a 12 column ListObject where column 12 has a formula. Without the vbNullString assignment, column 12 populates with the formula. As is, the formula is lost.

```
Sub TestLOFormulas()

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 11) As Variant

    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
    lo.DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete

    'This line clears the 'cache'
    lo.ListColumns(12).Range.Value = vbNullString

    arr(1, 1) = 1
    arr(1, 2) = 1
    arr(1, 3) = 1
    arr(1, 4) = 1
    arr(1, 5) = 1
    arr(1, 6) = 1
    arr(1, 7) = 1
    arr(1, 8) = 1
    arr(1, 9) = 1
    arr(1, 10) = 1
    arr(1, 11) = 1

    lo.InsertRowRange.Resize(1, 11).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test it now, and will let you know. The array thing looks rather long, i'll try to just use the lo.ListColumns(12).Range.Value = vbNullString :-)

Comment: The array thing was just me testing populating cells that don't have a formula, to see if the formula magically reappears.